# How do I learn to play the flute with vibrato?

Tags: flute, vibrato

There are a few songs I've been playing that I would like to add some vibrato to (I think it sounds so beautiful), but I can't get the technique down. (I'm self taught since there are no flautists in my area.)

If anyone could help me out with a few tips or how-tos that would be awesome!

Comment: related question [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/what-are-some-good-tips-for-vibrato-on-a-bassoon?s=9|0.8615)

Answer (score 2):

Vibrate your soft palette to interrupt the airflow - a back-of-the moth growl applied to a Scottish ch "loch" consonant. Your tonguing and embouchure continues uninterrupted, also learn to move the airflow around your mouth (much as you probably do in adjusting your embouchure to sometimes play from the side of your lips to get a stronger attack).

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like saxophone (which I'm sure it is) you just gotta add some controlled pulses in your air flow.  Kinda like 'who who who'...